# Asterisk - Macro not available

Tags: asterisk, dolibarr

I need some help here.
I try to configure dolibarr's plugin "Calling" on my asterisk.
I need to configure my extensions.conf so that all incoming calls on my asterisk return information to my dolibarr in order to have call notifications...

When I call from outside my softphone rings correctly, but as soon as I get off I get the following error message:

```
WARNING[3314][C-0000000d]: app.c:326 ast_app_exec_macro: Cannot run 'Macro(dolinotif)'.  The application is not available.
```

Here my `Extensions.conf` :

```
[Entrant] exten => s,1,Goto(dolibarr_notification,s,1) ;Redirection
exten => _X.,1,NoOp()
exten =>  _X.,n,Set(__DOLI_CALLER=${CUT(CUT(SIP_HEADER(From),@,1),:, 2)})
exten =>  _X.,n,Set(__DOLI_CALLE=${CUT(CUT(SIP_HEADER(To),@,1),:, 2)})

[macro-dolinotif]
exten => s,1,SET(${CURL(https://url.com/htdocs/custom/calling/calling.php?account=${EXTEN}&caller=${DOLI_CALLER}&callee=${DOLI_CALLE}&type=CONNECT&callref=${DOLI_CALLER}&version=1)})

[dolibarr_notification]
exten => s,1,SET(CALLERID(name)=${CURL(https://url.com/htdocs/custom/calling/calling.php?account=${USERNAME}&caller=${DOLI_CALLER}&callee=${DOLI_CALLE}&type=SETUP&callref=${DOLI_CALLER}&version=1)})
exten => s,n,Answer()
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/MY_NUMBER,60,etTrM(dolinotif))
exten => h,1,SET(CALLERID(name)=${CURL(https://url.com/htdocs/custom/calling/calling.php?account=${USERNAME}&caller=${DOLI_CALLER}&callee=${DOLI_CALLE}&type=RELEASE&callref=${DOLI_CALLER}&version=1)})
exten => h,2,Hangup(16)
```

I'm a begineer on Asterisk, maybe it's just a dumb problem... If you need more informations ask me.

Thank a lot.

Comment: maybe you can use U parameter instead of Macro.Because you dont send any Argument. `U(x): Executes, via gosub, routine x on the called channel. This is similar to M above, but a gosub rather than a macro`

Answer (score 0):

Use older asterisk version or rewrite your dialplan to use Gosub instead of macros.